# Need proof/counterexample for boundary of star shaped domain

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

A set $S$ in the Euclidean space $ \mathbb R^n $ is called a star shaped domain if there exists $x_o$ in $S$ such that for all $x$ in $S$ the line segment from $x_0$ to $x$ is in $S$.

Is the $\partial S$ always connected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In $\mathbb{R}$, the set $[0,1]$ is star-shaped and its boundary is $\{0,1\}$.

In dimension $2$ : take the strip $\{(x,y) | -1<y<1 \}$. It is star-shaped, but its boundary if the union of the two lines $y=1$ and $y=-1$ and is not connected.

I guess we could build higher-dimensional counterexamples on the same style, with unbounded star-shaped regions.

Comment: This is a nice example, but how about higher dimensions?

Comment: counter-example added !

Comment: Nice! Your argument can easily be seen to work for any dimension. It remains to see what happens in the bounded case.

Comment: I really can't find a counter-example with $S$ bounded in $\mathbb{R}^2$...

Comment: I strongly believe it should be true for connected sets, hence for star-shaped sets.

Comment: @TlönUqbarOrbisTertius If $S$ is bounded and dimension $\ge2$ then I suppose that $\partial S$ is even path connected

Comment: @TlönUqbarOrbisTertius +1, Thank you!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Can you please sketch a proof/give a reference for bounded case ?

Comment: If S is bounded and dimension ≥2, its boundary is not necessarily  path connected. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polar+plot+r%3D+2%2Bsin(-pi%5E2%2Ftheta),+0%3Ctheta+%5Cleq+2pi