# Suppose $S$ is bounded star shaped subset of $ \mathbb R^n$ where $n \ge 2$ then $ \partial S$ is path connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

**Def:** A set $S$ in the Euclidean space $ \mathbb R^n $ is called a star shaped domain if there exists $x_o$ in $S$ such that for all $x$ in $S$ the line segment from $x_0$ to $x$ is in $S$.

Some days ago in a comment in the answer to [one of my questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322299/need-proof-counterexample-for-boundary-of-star-shaped-domain) @Hagen Von Eitzen commented that

> Suppose $S$ is bounded  star shaped subset of $ \mathbb R^n$ where $n \ge 2$ then $ \partial S$ is Path connected.

I am unable to prove this result. Please help!

Comment: Please don't change the original questions once they've been answered. Instead accept the answer and create a new post with your new question. I've edited your post to leave it as it was before you completely changed it.

Comment: Also, it is in that exact question where someone provided a counter example to the connectedness of general star-shaped sets.

Comment: @hjhjhj57 Sorry..now I've asked a new question.Regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's another example. Let $(r,\phi)$ be the polar coordinates in $\mathbb R^2$. Define $S$ as the closure of $$\left\{(r,\phi)\mid r\leq2+\sin\frac{30}{\phi(2\pi-\phi)}\right\},$$ where we only allow $r\geq 0$ and $\phi\in(0,2\pi)$. [See here for a picture.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolarPlot[2%20%2B%20Sin[30%2F%28x%20%282%20Pi%20-%20x%29%29]%2C%20%7Bx%2C%200%2C%202%20Pi%7D])

This is star shaped pretty much by definition (since for each $\phi$ it contains all the points of at most a certain distance from the origin) and its boundary is a variant of the [Warsaw circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_theory_%28mathematics%29#Warsaw_Circle) and is not path connected.

Comment: Awesome! Here you can see the curve: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polar+plot+r%3D+1%2B+sin%28pi%5E2+%2F+phi%29%2C+phi+from+0+to+2pi

Comment: From the cruve probided by hjhjhj57, it seems that the curve is path connected? Actually the Warsaw curve is path connected, isn't it?

Comment: @hjhjhj57 : I just edited my comment. In any case it is path connected.

Comment: @John according to http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Warsaw+circle#properties it isn't.

Comment: @John: You're right, thanks for the comment. I used the wrong variant of the Warsaw circle, now it should be ok.

Comment: Nice example! ${}{}$

Comment: is this set open? cause a domain must be open

Comment: @Twnk: The definition as stated in the question does not require $S$ to be open, and indeed in my example, it is not open. If you need an open set with the same properties, you can simply take the interior of the set from my answer (note that this has the same boundary).

Answer (score 3):

It seems that this is not true.

For example, consider the following subset in $\mathbb R^2$.

For each $n\in \mathbb N$ consider the points $p_n = (\frac 1n, 1)$ and $p_{n+1}=(\frac{1}{n+1}, 1)$. Then consider the closed polygon $U_n$ formed by the vertices

$$O=(0,0), p_{n+1}, q_n = \left(\frac{2n+1}{4n(n+1)}, \frac 12\right), p_n$$

Note that this is a star convex set, with the center $(0, 0)$. (The third point is chosen this way: Let $D$ be the midpoint of $p_n, p_{n+1}$. Then the line $OD$ will hit $y=\frac{1}{2}$ at one point, which is $q_n $).

Now let

$$U_1 = \overline{\bigcup_n U_n} = \bigcup_n U_n \cup \{(0,y): 0\le y\le 1\},$$  and let

$$U = \{(x, y): (|x|, |y|)\in U_1\}\cup\{(x, y): |y|\le |x|\le 1\}$$

Then $U$ is a closed star convex set with center $(0,0)$, but the boundary is not path connected (only connected). The reason is that the boundary contains the segment $\{(0, y): \frac 12\le |y|\le 1\}$ and the boundary on both sides converges to these two segments as in the case of topological sine curve.

Comment: +1,Beautiful ! Sorry..How did u think about constructing such example?

Comment: To construct a connected but not path connected set, one will think of the topologist's sine curve. But it is hard to show that the sine curve is star convex with respect to any point, so instead of sine function I use straight lines. @Learner

Comment: Ah,I see.One more question:Do you believe that $ \partial S$ will always be connected?

Comment: I would believe that, but I can't think of a proof for now.

Comment: Thank you @John,I also beleive that $\partial S$ will be connected.If you find some proof please do add it in your answer.Regards,